# two datasets - sql reporting services 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services

please can someone help.

I have two datasets I'm working with and two tables.  I've managed to do one expression correct so do not understand why my second won't work.

My first expression is where I need to state the target number based on a result e.g.

```
=IIF(Fields!Line.Value = "B1", "10", IIF(Fields!Line.Value = "C1", "15", ""))
```

This works okay, but my next expression doesn't - here I'm trying to bring the result of B Line or C Line e.g.

```
=IIf(Fields!Line.Value="B1", Sum(Fields!Result.Value, "DataSet2"), IIF(Fields!LineName.Value = "B3", sum(Fields!Result.Value, "DataSet2"),""))
```

With this last formula it brings up the same information for all the lines, it doesn't take into account my IIF statement, so e.g. instead of it bringing 60 for Line B, and 40 for Line C, it brings up 100 for both B and C.

Can you tell me where I'm going wrong please.

Regards, AM

Answer (score 0):

Right now, your formula is adding all the whole dataset column up and returning the sum.  I think you would have to correct your IIF statement to get the related result.

Comment: Yes that's the problem i've got, i've tried various ways to write the code but I'm getting nowhere, it either adds the whole column up or I get an error message.  I've tried googling for answers as well.
Regards,